# Any way to forward an auth session from OAuth system to another system (with API key)?

Tags: authentication, docker, oauth

**Description**

This is a long shot, but I'm in dire need of advice. If you know of a more appropriate forum for this type of question please share!

I'm working with a legacy OAuth system using email + password grant type (deprecated, I know: it's out of my control).

I have to somehow connect this authentication service with a database backend for which I have an API key for.

**Existing architecture**

- Frontend application of our creation
- Legacy pingidentity OAuth service (must remain as is)
- Legacy backend (must remain as is)

Everything already exists other than whatever middleware solution that should handle the authentication validation and request header modifying.

---

**Ideal flow**

1. User logs in with OAuth service with email + password, gets access token
2. User sends backend request to some middleware, which does introspection / validates access token
3. Middleware appends API key to request header to retrieve backend data

[image]

**Things I've considered**

1. Traefik instance + [auth forwarding](https://hub.docker.com/r/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth)
   This seems to expect authentication to be done in the middleware rather than passing and introspecting an access token. Also **the OAuth service's introspection endpoint requires client ID and client secret** [as documented here](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf83/index.shtml#adminGuide/pf_c_introspectionParameters.html).
2. [Ory Oathkeeper](https://www.ory.sh/docs/oathkeeper/pipeline/authn#oauth2_introspection)
   This seems to expect arguments which would be used for regular OAuth2 redirect flow, such as `pre_authorization`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Does the legacy OAuth service not provide a token? In your diagram, which parts are missing or not functioning the way you want?

Comment: So the legacy OAuth service is PingFederate?    Could you federate it with a different OAuth provider which would be under your control, so that you can decouple your new system from the legacy OAuth service?    For example:   https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/enterprise-identity-providers/ping-federate

Comment: @GregBurghardt I can see that my post was missing context. I've added some more information and updated the diagram. Yes, the legacy OAuth service has a working token endpoint and working introspection endpoint, but these are unfortunately not associated with the backend service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with Ory Oathkeeper.

There is an unmerged pull request there which makes it possible to authenticate against some URL before forwarding the request + response.

Most importantly this method forwards all request elements. In this case I needed the body to be forwarded for the client ID + secret.

[This is the mentioned PR.](https://github.com/ory/oathkeeper/pull/949)

The `authenticator` configuration looks like this:

```yml
authenticators:
  remote_json:
    enabled: true
    config:
      service_url: <REDACTED>
      preserve_path: true
      method: "POST"
```